# PyQt Unbound Method When Passing Argument Between Signal and Slot

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am working on a project in which I need to download and parse an XML file from a network location. I've been trying to use the QtNetwork module to accomplish this, but I'm running into a seemingly simple problem that I've spent many hours trying to solve. My code is as follows:

```
class NetworkAccessor(QObject):
    done = False
    def importXml(self):
        self.manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.fileReady(QNetworkReply))
        self.manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://192.168.5.243/details.xml")))

    def fileReady(self, response):
        self.f = QTemporaryFile()
        print type(response)
        self.f.write(response.readAll())
        self.done = True
        print "Done"
```

When I instantiate the NetworkAccessor class and call importXml, I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/SVN-Local/Thermal/PyQtTestTemplate.py", line 40, in updateUi

    f = networkAccessor.importXml()

  File "C:/SVN-Local/Thermal/PyQtTestTemplate.py", line 14, in importXml

    self.connect(self.manager,SIGNAL("finished(QNetworkReply*)"),self.fileReady(QNetworkReply))

  File "C:/SVN-Local/Thermal/PyQtTestTemplate.py", line 20, in fileReady

    self.f.write(response.readAll())

TypeError: QIODevice.readAll(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QIODevice'`

It seems to indicate that the argument passed to the fileReady method is not instantiated. Furthermore, the `print type(response)` statement above indicates that `response` is of type `PyQt4.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply`.

I've tried various ways of connecting the signal to the slot including the "old fashioned" way: `self.connect(self.manager,SIGNAL("finished(QNetworkReply*)"),self.fileReady("QNetworkReply"))` as well as using short-circuit parameter passing with no success.

Can somebody show me the proper way to pass an instantiated instance of a QNetworkReply object from a signal to a slot?

Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out. The finished signal wasn't being emitted in my program, but when I specified the slot in the way that I did, the slot method was being called immediately and passing an uninstantiated QNetworkReply object to the method.

So now that raises another question: Why is the finished flag not being raised? The file is only a few kilobytes in length and I'm certain the address is correct. The file is being updated every second or so, however, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it the slot, the QNetworkReply object will get passed through by the signal:

```
self.manager.finished.connect(self.fileReady)
```